# How to mlock all pages of a process tree from console?

Tags: linux, memory, process

"mlockall() locks all pages mapped into the address space of the calling process"

How to do it from console for a process tree?

Something like `lockall sh -c "read_data | process_data | write_data"`, in style of `nice`, `ionice` and `schedtool -e`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Implemented myself: libmlockall.

LD_PRELOAD it and it will call mlockall for each process it is being loaded into.

http://github.com/vi/libmlockall